# How to implement IDisposable interface in a class inherited from SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, inheritance, dispose, idisposable, socketasynceventargs

I work on a huge project in C# .NET 4.0. There is a custom class inherited from [System.Net.Sockets.**SocketAsyncEventArgs**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.100).aspx) class. Something like the following:

```
public class SocketTaskArgs : SocketAsyncEventArgs
{
    public SocketTaskArgs()
    {
        Completed += someEventhHandler;
    }

    public void CleanUp()
    {
        Completed -= someEventhHandler;
    }

    /* 
        There is a lot of code here that is unimportant at the moment.
    */
}
```

So, I wanted to move the content of CleanUp() method to Dispose(bool) method.

As first, I checked the source code of the base class - SocketAsyncEventArgs (using **Go To Definition** so that I saw metadata as source). I found out, this class implements IDisposable interface. Nice, I just need to override the Dispose(bool) method, don't I? (See [IDisposable Interface on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx), the "*IDisposable and the inheritance hierarchy*" section, for more details). Nothing new for me... Unfortunately, the SocketAsyncEventArgs class is implemented as following:

```
public class SocketAsyncEventArgs : EventArgs, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose();

    //some other stuff here
}
```

That means, there is no way how to override *Dispose(bool)* method, as it's implemented as *private* instead of *protected*... **What is the reason for this?**

Next, I read about [SocketAsyncEventArgs.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.dispose(v=vs.100).aspx) method on MSDN. The funny thing is that, it contains the following section:

> **Notes to Inheritors**
>
> **Dispose** can be called multiple times by other
>   objects. When overriding **Dispose(Boolean)**, be careful not to reference
>   objects that have been previously disposed of in an earlier call to
>   **Dispose**. For more information about how to implement **Dispose(Boolean)**,
>   see Implementing a Dispose Method.

Wait... what?

> When overriding **Dispose(Boolean)**, ...

**How am I supposed to override Dispose(Boolean)?**

**What is the recommended way to implement IDisposable interface in this case?**

Comment: Its not private, its not implemented at all (see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs.html#8877). It does use a finalizer but looks like it wasn't really implemented in the recommended pattern.

Comment: It looks like `Dispose` is public, just not `virtual`.

Comment: You're not supposed to inherit from that class. You probably can't change that easily in a big existing project.

Comment: @RonBeyer it looks like you're right and SocketAsyncEventArgs class was really not implemented in the recommended pattern... Anyway, good to know, that the .NET sour code is available. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @usr I'd think, that I'm not supposed to inherit from it. There is no such information on the MSDN page and the class is not sealed, so why not? Anyway, you are right, that I cannot do a major change to the code at the moment, as it would require a lot of testing...

Comment: Normally you'd wrap it. Misuse of inheritance (mostly). Normally inheritance is for substitution of different behaviors. For example Stream or IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be anything stopping you from implementing `IDisposable` on your child class, take this example:

```
public class DisposableParent : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The parent was disposed.");
    }
}

public class DisposableChild : DisposableParent, IDisposable
{
    public new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
        Console.WriteLine("The child was disposed.");
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
         using (DisposableChild c = new DisposableChild()) { }
         Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Gives the following output:

> The parent was disposed.
>
> The child was disposed.

The compiler warns about hiding the dispose of the parent class in the child, so using the `new` operator gets rid of that warning, just make sure to call the base class `Dispose` from the child class (and implement it the right way).

The dispose for the child would become something like:

```
public class DisposableChild : DisposableParent, IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                base.Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine("The child was disposed.");
                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And yes, this still works if you do something like:

```
using (DisposableParent p = new DisposableChild())
{

}
```

But something like this can break it:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DisposableChild c = new DisposableChild();
        DisposeOfIt(c);

        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public static void DisposeOfIt(DisposableParent p)
    {
        p.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Only prints out that the parent was disposed. So if you used this method you would have to be careful about controlling the lifetime of your objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with you, that I can implement IDisposable interface on my inherited class. That was actually the first thing that came to my mind. I'm just curious if somebody will come with another and maybe a better idea. If there is nothing better in the near future, I'll mark your answer as accepted.